# Targeting IE CSS with IF

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I attempted using IF to target specific CSS changes for IE.

Though, for some reason it wont work.

Am I doing something wrong?

---

```
<!--[if IE 8]> <style type="text/css"> @media only screen and (min-width: 900px) { html body div.left div.info ul li p.text-01:after { margin: -4% 0 0 -11%; font-size: 60px; } html body div.left div.info ul li p.text-02:after { margin: -4% 0 0 -11%; font-size: 60px; } html body div.left div.info ul li p.text-03:after { margin: -4% 0 0 -11%; font-size: 60px; } html body div.right div.info ul li p.text-02:after { margin: -4% 0 0 -11%; font-size: 60px; } html body div.right div.info ul li p.text-03:after { margin: -4% 0 0 -11%; font-size: 60px; } } </style> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <style type="text/css"> @media only screen and (min-width: 900px) { html body div.left div.info ul li p.text-01:after { margin: -4% 0 0 -11%; font-size: 60px; } html body div.left div.info ul li p.text-02:after { margin: -4% 0 0 -11%; font-size: 60px; } html body div.left div.info ul li p.text-03:after { margin: -4% 0 0 -11%; font-size: 60px; } html body div.right div.info ul li p.text-02:after { margin: -4% 0 0 -11%; font-size: 60px; } html body div.right div.info ul li p.text-03:after { margin: -4% 0 0 -11%; font-size: 60px; } } </style> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 10]> <style type="text/css"> @media only screen and (min-width: 900px) { html body div.left div.info ul li p.text-01:after { margin: -4% 0 0 -11%; font-size: 60px; } html body div.left div.info ul li p.text-02:after { margin: -4% 0 0 -11%; font-size: 60px; } html body div.left div.info ul li p.text-03:after { margin: -4% 0 0 -11%; font-size: 60px; } html body div.right div.info ul li p.text-02:after { margin: -4% 0 0 -11%; font-size: 60px; } html body div.right div.info ul li p.text-03:after { margin: -4% 0 0 -11%; font-size: 60px; } } </style> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 11]> <style type="text/css"> @media only screen and (min-width: 900px) { html body div.left div.info ul li p.text-01:after { margin: -4% 0 0 -11%; font-size: 60px; } html body div.left div.info ul li p.text-02:after { margin: -4% 0 0 -11%; font-size: 60px; } html body div.left div.info ul li p.text-03:after { margin: -4% 0 0 -11%; font-size: 60px; } html body div.right div.info ul li p.text-02:after { margin: -4% 0 0 -11%; font-size: 60px; } html body div.right div.info ul li p.text-03:after { margin: -4% 0 0 -11%; font-size: 60px; } } </style> <![endif]-->
```

Thanks.

Comment: At least your IF is targeting IE finely. there must be some problem with css.
also you can try one line instead of four.
<!--[if gt IE 7]><![endif]-->

Comment: IE10 and later no longer support conditional comments. And IE8 and earlier don't support media queries, so that one won't work for you either.

Comment: You shouldn't need browser-specific code for any of that code anyway (except for the lack of media query support in IE8), so really none of this code should be necessary anyway. If you think you do need it, then you're probably doing something wrong; maybe you should ask about that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are hacks for css to target ie9+ such as this:

```
/* target Internet Explorer 9 and Internet Explorer 10:*/

    @media screen and (min-width:0\0) { 
        /* ie9+ code here */
        ...
    }
```

Check this example **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/pyvL6/1/)** in IE9+ and other browsers

Answer (score 3):

[Conditional comments were removed in IE10 and later](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Support for conditional comments has been removed in Internet Explorer
>   10 standards and quirks modes for improved interoperability and
>   compliance with HTML5. This means that Conditional Comments are now
>   treated as regular comments, just like in other browsers. This change
>   can impact pages written exclusively for Windows Internet Explorer or
>   pages that use browser sniffing to alter their behavior in Internet
>   Explorer.

Additionally, [media queries don't work in IE8](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries), so essentially your code will only ever work in IE9.

Answer (score 0):

Tryout this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <style type="text/css">
    @media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
      html body div.left div.info ul li p.text-01:after {
        margin: -4% 0 0 -11%; font-size: 60px;
      }
      html body div.left div.info ul li p.text-02:after {
        margin: -4% 0 0 -11%; font-size: 60px;
      }
      html body div.left div.info ul li p.text-03:after {
        margin: -4% 0 0 -11%; font-size: 60px;
      }
      html body div.right div.info ul li p.text-02:after {
        margin: -4% 0 0 -11%; font-size: 60px;
      }
      html body div.right div.info ul li p.text-03:after {
        margin: -4% 0 0 -11%; font-size: 60px;
      }
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: See my comment: This won't work in IE8, IE10 or IE11.